# Ruby on Rails / Bootstrap : dynamic datas in a modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I am beginning with Ruby on Rails and have a question about the use of the bootstrap's modal.
So my problem is that i have a table and for each row of this table i make a button to display with the modal some other informations about dependent classes but it displays the right informations only for the first row and the same ones for all other rows. I want to make it dynamic and corresponding to the object it deals with.

```
      <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Priority</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>

        <% @user_stories.each do |user_story| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= user_story.id %></td>
            <td><%= user_story.name %></td>
            <td><%= user_story.description %></td>
            <td><%= user_story.priority %></td>
            <td><%= user_story.state %></td>

            <td>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary">Options</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><%= link_to 'Show', user_story %></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_story_path(user_story) %></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li> <%= link_to 'Destroy', user_story, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </td>
            <td> <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Global View</a></td>
            <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3 id="myModalLabel">Golbal view : <%= user_story.name %></h3>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                        <% us = user_story.functionalities %>
                        <% us.each do |f| %>
                        <span class="label label-info"><%= f.name %></span>
                        <% t = f.tasks%>
                        <br/>
                            <% t.each do |y| %>
                            <%= y.name %>
                            <% u = User.where(:id => y.user_id) %>
                            <%= u.collect {|p|  ": #{p.first_name} #{p.last_name}"} %>
                            <br/>
                            <% end %>
                        <br/>
                        <% end %>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>

              </div>
            </div>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
        </table>
```

Any ideas how to fix it ?

Routes:

```
Backlog::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :functionalities

    resources :user_stories

    resources :users

    resources :tasks
end
```

Comment: Can you share your routes for that?

Comment: @BachanSmruty: done

But what's the relationship with the routes ?

Comment: Sorry! miss read your question first time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have added the modal to every row.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

But here for the every row the id of the modal is same. So you are getting the same dialog for every row. You need to make dynamic id for for the modals and wherever you are using id in the modal div.

```
<a href="#myModal<%= user_story.id%>" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Global View</a>
<div id="myModal<%= user_story.id%>" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3 id="myModalLabel<%= user_story.id%>">Golbal view : <%= user_story.name %></h3>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                        <% us = user_story.functionalities %>
                        <% us.each do |f| %>
                        <span class="label label-info"><%= f.name %></span>
                        <% t = f.tasks%>
                        <br/>
                            <% t.each do |y| %>
                            <%= y.name %>
                            <% u = User.where(:id => y.user_id) %>
                            <%= u.collect {|p|  ": #{p.first_name} #{p.last_name}"} %>
                            <br/>
                            <% end %>
                        <br/>
                        <% end %>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>

              </div>
            </div>
```